# multi background-image don't work with position

Tags: css

```
#example1 {width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(http://www.css3.info/wp-content/themes/new_css3/img/sheep.png), 
url(http://www.css3.info/wp-content/themes/new_css3/img/sheep.png);
background-position: 20px 10px, 100px 250px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}​
```

Background-image with fixed background-position don't work [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JGVHG/)

Comment: What browser version are you testing this on?

Comment: Chrome latest, IE 9, Firefox 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having same value for height and last number in background position. Change to this and see.

```
background-position: 20px 10px, 100px 100px;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JGVHG/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Write it as -

```
#example1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(http://www.css3.info/wp-content/themes/new_css3/img/sheep.png) no-repeat 20px 10px, url(http://www.css3.info/wp-content/themes/new_css3/img/sheep.png) no-repeat 200px 50px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JGVHG/2/)

Your code also works but the problem with your code is that you are setting top position of the second image at 250px; where the height of your container is 250px; That's why it's not visible :)